# Programmatically change SQL Server configuration

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I want to backup database in SQL Server 2012 using this code:

```
BACKUP DATABASE aveed_co
TO DISK = 'C:\bakup.bak'
WITH FORMAT,
MEDIANAME = 'aveed_co',
NAME = 'aveed_co'
```

After execution this code in SQL Server Management Studio, I get this error:

> Msg 233, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server.
>   (provider: Shared Memory Provider, `error: 0` - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

To solve this problem I must change log on type (in SQL Server configuration) as below:

[image]

In other hand I must change "log on as" from "Built-in account" (1) to "This account" (2).

When I change "log on as" to "This account" and enter username and password the SQL Server code execute correctly.

Note that I have permission to write on c: or any driver

Please help me to do this using C# or SQL Server code.

Comment: Security context is established before code is run; how are you connecting to the server in order to run your code?  Are you writing an app, or using SSMS?

Comment: Did you tried these solutions ["Troubleshooting: No Process Is on the Other End of the Pipe"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175496(v=sql.105).aspx) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have write permissions on drive C: for your custom user.
EDIT:

```
        var query = @"BACKUP DATABASE [aveed_co] 
                        TO  DISK = 'C:\bakup.bak' WITH  INIT 
                        ,NOUNLOAD
                        ,NAME = N'aveed_co'
                        ,NOSKIP
                        ,STATS = 10
                        ,NOFORMAT 
                        ,COMPRESSION";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=myServerAddress;Database=aveed_co;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

SQL Server must be able to read and write to the device; the account under which the SQL Server service runs must have write permissions.

Comment: Thank from every body... Specially Adrian Trifan